# Mod_Rewrite - Need Help With Old Url And Query String To New Url And Query String RewriteRu

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, querystring

How would I rewrite the following using mod_rewrite with wildcards:

```
http://www.serverurl.com/glossary/WordFind.php?wordInput=(Dynamic Wildcard Word Here)
```

to:

```
http://www.serverurl.com/index.php?option=com_glossary&Itemid=326&view=word&word=(Dynamic Wildcard Word Here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and got this to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^wordInput=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/glossary/WordFind\.php.*$ /index.php?option=com_glossary&Itemid=326&view=word&word=%1 [R]
```

Comment: My original RewriteCond was against the URI instead of the Query String.  I tested this out and it seems to work.

Comment: I got this to kind of work:

Comment: i eventualy got this to kind of work `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^wordInput=(.*)
RewriteRule ^glossary/wordfind\.php index.php?option=com_glossary&Itemid=326&view=word&word=%1` However the url it produces stil contains the wordfind.php. keep in mind the fact that all urls are rewritten to lowercase. Thanks for the help so far. @Sean, youve got me closer to the solution.

Comment: isnt there a special character for removing the original query string?

Comment: I think you need the / in front of index.php to specify the proper URL.  index.php is on the root, is it not?  `RewriteRule ^glossary/wordfind\.php /index.php?option=com_glossary&Itemid=326&view=word&word=%1`

Comment: No it totally breaks with that "/"..I should add that i have aceSEF installed and its in joomla..However this is all in the .htacces before anything even gets to joomla.